# Function acts differently with arguments hard coded

Tags: jquery, function

and sorry in advance that I don't know the terminology for the problem I am having.
Essentially this hardcoded version works as expected:

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "#contactLink", loadContact);

function loadContact () {
    $("#navbar ul li a").removeClass("selected");
    $("#contactLink").addClass("selected");
    $("#page").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $("#content").load("TGCContact.html .insert", function() {
            $("#page").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
    return false;
}
```

but the below version pauses for the 500ms (including 'selected' link update) then empties #content and jumps straight to fadeIn():

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "#contactLink", function(){
    loadContact('TGCContact.html .insert', '#contactLink');
});

function loadContact (htmlPage, newLink) {
    $("#navbar ul li a").removeClass("selected");
    $(newLink).addClass("selected");
    $("#page").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $("#content").load(htmlPage, function() {
            $("#page").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
    return false;
}
```

The hardcoded version is nice and smooth.  Can somebody please explain why this happens and how to work around it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle for this?

Comment: The fadeOut call with 500 as a parameter may have something to do with that...

Comment: After a bit more research it seems to be an issue with passing a function call instead of a function reference.
Could it be that in the second example the loadContact function is being called?  It does seem that passing function(){loadContact(...);} is a valid reference.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I see wrong in the second version is that you lose the effect intended by `return false` which is to prevent the default behaviour (`event.preventDefault()` is often better suited).

So without the HTML one can assume there is a URL there and the page will do something which may cause unwanted effects.

So you can either return the result of the called function as such

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "#contactLink", function(){
    return loadContact('TGCContact.html .insert', '#contactLink');
});
```

Or simply lose `return false` in the function and do it in the handler

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "#contactLink", function(){
    loadContact('TGCContact.html .insert', '#contactLink');
    return false;
});
```

`event.preventDefault` way

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "#contactLink", function(event){
    loadContact('TGCContact.html .insert', '#contactLink');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gillesc! The second example with 'return false' outside of the loadContact() function did the trick.  I also want stopPropagation as I have listeners on the navbar itself, so okay with return false in this case.